# Demeaned fixed effects invariant to base category

Tags: economics, least-squares, parameter-estimation

Consider the following regression equation:
$\gamma_{ib}=\beta_{b}+\alpha_{i}$. Where $\gamma_{ib}$ is matched bank-firm loan growth between $t$ and $t-1$. $\beta_{b}$ is a set of $B$ dummies (one for each bank) and $\alpha_{i}$ is a set of $F-1$ firm dummies (where one firm is dropped to avoid perfect multicollinearity). There is multibank lending such that each firm borrows from multiple banks. Important: there is no constant. There is no time dimension.

Suppose I estimate the following two regressions seperately (OLS): 1.
$\gamma_{ib}=\beta_{b}+\alpha_{i}$ where firm 1 is exluded in $\alpha_{i}$ and 2. $\gamma_{ib}=\beta'_{b}+\alpha'_{i}$ where firm 2 is excluded (and firm 1 included). Of course, $\beta_{b}\neq \beta'_{b}$.  If, in a next step, I demean in the estimated $\hat{\beta_{b}}$ and $\beta'_{b}$, I find that the resulting vectors of fixed effects are the same, i.e.

$\hat{\beta_{b}}-\frac{1}{B}\sum_{b}\hat{\beta_{b}}=\hat{\beta'_{b}}-\frac{1}{B}\sum_{b}\hat{\beta'_{b}}$

Is it possible to formally show the more broader result that the demeaned bank fixed effects are the same no matter which firm fixed effect is dropped?

Answer (score 0):

First, it's not clear to me why you want to de-mean fixed effects.

Anyway, the reason that the $\beta$s change is because by changing the base for $\alpha$, you're changing the "constant". Recall that even with no explicit constant term, the sum of the bank fixed effects will be 1 and thus the sum of the betas will be equivalent to a constant.

What will be left unchanged is the *difference* between the $\beta$s.

Therefore for every $b$

$\beta_b - \frac{1}{B}\sum_i \beta_i  = \frac{1}{B} \sum_i \beta_b -  \frac{1}{B}\sum_i \beta_i = \frac{1}{B} \sum_i (\beta_b - \beta_i) $

and similarly

$\beta'_b - \frac{1}{B}\sum_i \beta'_i   = \frac{1}{B} \sum_i (\beta'_b - \beta'_i) $

Since $\beta_b - \beta_i = \beta'_b - \beta'_i$ for all $b,i$ these two expressions must be identical.